# Why is there a left-shift in ConTeXt's \setuparranging

Tags: context-mkiv

In [this page arranging example](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definepapersize), why don't the green lines align with the black lines?

Comment: We prefer self contained questions rather than just a link. Could you post here all the details (a minimal document to compile, may be with the images, a detailed explanation…).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is by design, quoting from [`page-lay.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/87d82131e6359a9bb3fb4e85e2f26f6864de8ac9/tex/context/base/mkiv/page-lay.mkiv#L1353-L1358)

> ```
> %D The default dimensions are quite old and will not change.
> %D The funny fractions were introduced when we went from fixed
> %D dimensions to relative ones. Since \CONTEXT\ is a dutch
> %D package, the dimensions are based on the metric system. The
> %D asymmetrical layout is kind of handy for short
> %D quick||and||dirty stapled documents.
> ```